# How to write Command Like Ping www.google.com using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

How can I write Command Like Ping www.google.com -t using C# and read the respond?

I need to make function act like :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         result     =Write_cmd("ping www.google.com -t");
         txt_result =result;

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't expect someone to write a complete solution for you. Reading some online examples should help you solve this yourself.

Comment: [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [And here a complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingcompletedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/c ping www.google.com -t";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

without "/c" cmd cannot run arguments.

Comment: **NOTE:** to get the output you just need to [redirect the standard output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thanks for your attention but when I dont know why when I write it I just get copy of my windows form and no cmd screen appear ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to run external commands, and even get the standard output. Read the examples there, and if you run into any problems, feel free to post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
            Process p = new Process(); //crete a process
            try
            {
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "www.google.com -t";
               // p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Note that the Process class is under the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Comment: thanks for your attention , In fact this way is working but : -->how to make some thing else like delete file usimg cmd? --> how to get respond back to my C# code ??  ==> how to make thw prmpot screen hidden??

Comment: Well, if you only want to delete a file, you could use the System.IO.File class. If you want to make hidden the promt screen uncomment the p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; in the example code. To get the output from the cmd, you could redirect the Standard Output (p.StandardOutput) and after executing the process you could read it.